# Can a router with USB support function as a file server?

Tags: networking

Are there any router like devices that would allow me to plug in a USB external HDD, and act like a local file server?

I currently have to plug my laptop in to an external HDD in order to access and share files on my home network. I want to eliminate this and access all the files without wires.

Comment: Most mid-range to high-end routers will support that. Just search on Amazon.

Comment: or: http://www.walmart.com/ip/Lacie-Wireless-Space-2TB-Desktop-External-Hard-Drive/15268498 < as example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of products in this category. Here's [one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822165451). A lot routers include this functionality. Just search for router with USB drive and/or NAS.

Answer (score 2):

There are many routers with USB support that can be flashed with open-source firmware like [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) and [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_Firmware).

I am using a [NETGEAR WNR3500Lv2](http://www.myopenrouter.com/category/70/WNR3500Lv2-Open-Source-Router) with [Tomato Firmware](http://www.myopenrouter.com/download/38605/Tomato-by-Shibby-for-WNR3500Lv2-v105-All-In-One/).

Here is a live demo of the [Tomato's USB/NAS page](http://victek.is-a-geek.com/virtual/tomatok26/nas-usb.html).

Here is the a [live demo of the DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/demo/index.asp). The features you're interested in are under the **Services** tab.